# Concatenation between two ItemSources

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, string-concatenation

Alright, so I'm trying to get a single combo-box in WPF to display two different column's data (Both are strings) that I'm importing from a SQL dataset.

Data I'm working with:
[image: Data I'm working with]

Currently, I have two separate combo-box's displaying a Category and a SubCategory (Two separate columns from my SQL Table), I no longer want to do that.

Current Combo_box's being displayed:
[image: Current Display]

I want to write a function that will concatenate both sets of data into a single combobox. (So, the Category_Combo_Box shown should display: "BillTrak Pro Feeds CABS AMIS STAGING" when all is said and done).

I'm not sure how to reference the dataset data from these rows in order to have it display correctly, especially if I delete the sub_category_combo_box, because I also don't know how to reference the datasource without binding it into a toolbox option..

My thought process right now - C#: (Keep in mind, I have no idea how to reference the SQL table's dataset, so I'm forced to use the combobox's item binding).

```
WpfApplication1.DataSet2 DS = ((WpfApplication1.DataSet2)(this.FindResource("dataSet2")));

string newstring = string.Concat("_", new String[] { "Category: ", Category_ComboBox.Items.ToString() , "SubCategory: ", SubCategory_ComboBox.Items.ToString() });

Category_ComboBox.Text = newstring;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it is better to concatenate strings in your SQL and get only two columns as output

Comment: So, make it concatenate in oracle, have it output the result in another column, and then just reference said column, instead of trying to do it in Visual Studio?

Comment: yes, that's it; if you need these two columns also separately for other purposes;

Comment: True. Any suggestions on how to do that? FOR XML PATH is the only way I've heard of doing it; however, I've never personally done it.

Comment: are you in Oracle or SQL Server? In Oracle - `SELECT Column1 || Column2 FROM Table`; `||` is your concatenating operator

Comment: Using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112828/discussion-between-sqlhelp-and-techspider).